# Add a new key and value to a Javascript object from an existing array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, ecmascript-6

I have an existing array of ids that I'm trying to iterate over to add each as an `id:` key to an existing array of objects. I have tried a number of different loops (for, for in, map, forEach), but I keep having the same outcome - it only adds the first id to each object, so `id: 'a'` x 6

An example of what I have

```
const ids = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

const objArr = [
  {
   property: "some value",
  }
  {
   property: "some value",
  }
  {
   property: "some value",
  }
  {
   property: "some value",
  }
  {
   property: "some value",
  }
  {
   property: "some value",
  }
]
```

An example of what I want to achieve

```
const objArr = [
  {
   property: "some value",
   id: 'a'
  }
  {
   property: "some value",
   id: 'b'
  }
  {
   property: "some value",
   id: 'c'
  }
  {
   property: "some value",
   id: 'd'
  }
  {
   property: "some value",
   id: 'e'
  }
  {
   property: "some value",
   id: 'f'
  }
]
```

Here is an example of a forEach loop with a nested for in loop which I have tried to no avail.

```
ids.forEach((item) => {
    for (const key in objArr) {
      objArr[key].id = item
    }
  })
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Your array is invalid. The commas should go between the objects.

Comment: Each iteration through `objArr` is overwriting the previous iteration's key.

Comment: @Andy sorry, missed that whilst writing it out. Will add for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just loop through `objArr` array and on each `item` inside add an `id` property which it's value equal to the item with the same `index` on the `ids` array.

```js
const ids = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

const objArr = [{
  property: "some value",
}, {
  property: "some value",
}, {
  property: "some value",
}, {
  property: "some value",
}, {
  property: "some value",
}, {
  property: "some value",
}]

objArr.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.id = ids[index];
})

console.log(objArr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are going through both arrays, but you only need to go through one and work with the index:

```
ids.forEach((id, index) => {
  objArr[index].id = id
})
```